# Is there a more pythonic way to use multiple list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

There is snippet of code with list comprehensions of similar type/task. Each of iterable in comprehension formula is of `numpy.array` `[(), (), ()]` shape. Is there more 'pythonic', not so repetitive way to write this?

```
conv_zcr = [bytes(x) for x in zcr]
conv_stft = [bytes(x) for x in stft]
conv_spectral_centroid = [bytes(x) for x in spectral_centroid]
```

Comment: You can always write a function to extract repetitive code :)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can try ziping it together if they have same `len` i guess:

```
conv_zcr, conv_stft, conv_spectral_centroid = [
    (bytes(x), bytes(y), bytes(z))
    for x, y, z in zip(zcr, stft, spectral_centroid)
]
```

you probably can `chain` em if mixing outputs is not an issue:

```
out = [bytes(x) for x in itertools.chain(zcr, stft, spectral_centroid)]
```

you can probably map them to something of your liking:

```
out = [map(bytes, ar) for ar in [zcr, stft, spectral_centroid]]
```

Comment: This one is really nice. You could even change `out` to `conv_zcr, conv_stft, conv_spectral_centroid` and let it be unpacked.

Comment: @Verthais, I think you want `(bytes(x), bytes(y), bytes(z))` to match the 3 zip arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map(...)` i suppose. But I don't think it is especially more pythonic.

```
conv_zcr = map(bytes, zcr)
conv_stft = map(bytes, stft)
conv_spectral_centroid = map(bytes, spectral_centroid)
```

Cast to `list()` like this `list(map(bytes, zcr))` if you don't want a lazy loading map object.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```py
def byteify_lists(*lists):
    return [[bytest(x) for x in lst] for lst in lists]

conv_zcr, conv_stft, conv_spectral_centroid = byteifly_lists(zcr, stft, spectral_centroid)
```

Or in a single list comprehension

```py
conv_zcr, conv_stft, conv_spectral_centroid = [[bytes(x) for x in lst] 
                                                for lst in 
                                                [zcr, stft, spetral_centroid]]
```

But honestly, the way you have it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which orientation you want from the three lists. However, in general, if you want a collection of objects to undergo the same set of steps, then normally the easiest way to work with that data is to place that data in a list. For example,

```
lists = [zcr, stft, spectral_centroid]
```

then if we want to apply bytes() to each entry in each list we can do so in several ways:

```
conv_lists = [[bytes(i) for i in l] for l in lists]
conv_lists = [list(map(bytes,l)) for l in lists]
```

if you want the elements oriented the other way, then you might want the zip() function:

```
conv_lists = [list(map(bytes,l)) for l in zip(*lists)]
```

if you want to place that result in a np.array(), then wrap that in np.array():

```
import numpy as np
conv_lists = np.array([list(map(bytes,l)) for l in zip(*lists)])
```